# Karma with jasmine does not print any useful error

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

There is an angular 15.2 project with karma + jasmine tests. The tests are failing in jenkins and there is virtually no information why.

```
Chrome Headless 117.0.5938.132 (Windows 10): Executed 4 of 227 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.292 secs)
Chrome Headless 117.0.5938.132 (Windows 10): Executed 5 of 227 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.325 secs)
Chrome Headless 117.0.5938.132 (Windows 10): Executed 5 of 227 (skipped 222) SUCCESS (0.418 secs / 0.325 secs)
11 11 2023 13:01:41.295:DEBUG [launcher]: CAPTURED -> BEING_KILLED
11 11 2023 13:01:41.295:DEBUG [launcher]: BEING_KILLED -> BEING_FORCE_KILLED
```

angular.json

```
            "test": {
                "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                "options": {
                    "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                    "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
                    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
```

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
        require('karma-jasmine'),
        require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
        require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
        require('karma-coverage'),
        require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
        captureConsole: true,
```

How can I get more information? I needed to run the test locally in a browser to see:

```
Chrome 117.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 5 of 227 (skipped 222) SUCCESS (0.361 secs / 0.287 secs)
Incomplete: fit() or fdescribe() was found, 5 specs, 0 failures, randomized with seed
```

Comment: It sounds like it succesfully exectuted 5 and skipped the rest? Do you have an `fdescribe `block with 5 test cases beneath it? or else, 5 `fit` test cases scattered in your test suite? Jasmine will skip the rest of your tests if it detects `fdescribe` and/or `fit`

Comment: Yes, there was a bug in the test. My concern is that the output was not clearly stating the error so it was harder to spot it.